# pick and place prevent box flip

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello
I am trying to make a pick and place application.
My goal is to move 4 boxes from one point to another.
while doing this I saw the boxes turn upside down and the arm carries the boxes with longer movements, sometimes it follows a nice path but sometimes it draws a longer path and turns the boxes upside down.
If I want to carry a tray, the glasses on the tray will spill.

Although I made the first joint and the last joint continuous, it was not solved, so I saw that the problem was not in the limit angles.

Here is a video explaining the situation.

[Video (38sec)](https://streamable.com/05xts3)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/415234/pick-and-place-prevent-box-flip/) by [omeranar1](https://answers.ros.org/users/45833/omeranar1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2023-05-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should look into a move_group feature called "orientation constraint". The idea is that you add restrictions on the pose of a specific arm link relative to some frame.

This feature performs these extra checks on the solution proposed by the OMPL planner, and it rejects solutions which are not compatible. I have not tried to use this feature myself, but comments on this website say you may have to increase the amount of time allowed for planning for it to find a workable solution.

I believe you will specify your constraint using a `moveit_msgs::OrientationConstraint` object.

Update: I found https://moveit.ros.org/moveit/2020/09/10/ompl-constrained-planning-gsoc.html which looks like an improved implementation of certain OMPL planners. I don't know if this improvement has been merged to any ros release.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2023-05-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [omeranar1](https://answers.ros.org/users/45833/omeranar1/) on 2023-05-16**:
thank you so much, problem has been solved